# AD Query for non expiring password but filter only active users

Tags: active-directory, directory, query

I need to do query which filters users with non expiring password setup.

I have something like this:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=65536))
```

It works but show even disabled accounts and some system accounts like (HealthMailbox).

Can i somehow filter to show only active users?

I tried this but it doesnt works:

```
(&(&(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=65536)))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to exclude the correct flag for disabled accounts:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=65536)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))
```